# Laravel: one model referencing two other models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an auction website with two tables: auctions and lots. Both auctions and lots (belonging to an auction) can contain images.

From a database point of view, I have created a table called images_auctions (having a foreign key to the auction ID) and a table called lots_images (having a foreign key to the lot ID).

I also have the following in my Auction Model:

```
class Auction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'auctions';

    public function lots() {
        return $this->hasMany(Lot::class);
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    } 
}
```

and also in the Lots model, I have:

```
   class Lot extends Model {

    protected $table = 'lots';

    public function auction() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Auction::class);
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
}
```

I then wanted to create an Image model that contains the following:

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'images';

    public function auction() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Auction::class);
    }

    public function lot() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lot::class);
    }    
}
```

Is it possible to have 1 model called Images that references both Auction and Lot (with the belongsTo method). Or should I create two models (ImageAuction and ImageLot) to achieve this?

Also, from a database point of view, are there better methods rather than creating two separate image tables (images_auctions and images_lots)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to have 1 model called Images that references both Auction and Lot. It calls Polymorphic Relations. 
**I. Model** 
*I.1. Lot Model*

```
class Lot extends Model
{
    public function auction() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Auction::class);
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
}
```

*I.2. Auction Model*

```
class Auction extends Model
{
    public function lots() {
        return $this->hasMany(Lot::class);
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
}
```

*I.3. Image Model*

```
class Image extends Model
{
    public function imageable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**II. Table structure**

```
auctions
    id - integer

lots
    id - integer
    auction_id - integer

images
    id - integer
    imageable_id - integer
    imageable_type - string
    image_link - string
```

**III. Example**

```
id    | imageable_id | imageable_type | image_link
1     |        1     |   App\Lot      |  img1
2     |        2     |   App\Auction  |  img2
```

**IV. Notice**
You should follow Laravel name convenient like above if you don't want to get a lot of headache.